# Brightness reduced after installation

Tags: brightness

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 the display brightness of my laptop has reduced. Increasing the brightness in system settings makes no change. Can you help me tackle this problem?

Comment: @Jai I think the "system settings" refers to the GUI,not CLI.

Comment: yeah but if its failed to do from there then he can do it from custom app launcher by those lines.

Comment: We need to know the model of your laptop, please add it to your question!